# airbnb/react-dates set blocked days after api fetch

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-dates

**Library**: https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

**Question**: Is possible to set blocked days after fetch from server? (wait/recall isDayBlocked callback or re-initialize calendar)

**Problem**: Callback 'isDayBlocked' is called after calendar changes view to next month when data are not ready yet.

Example Code:

```
import { DayPickerSingleDateController } from 'react-dates';

class DayPicker {

  isDayBlocked(day) {
    return this.days.has(day);
  }

  handleMonthChange() {
    // async api fetch
    this.days = getNextMonthBlockedDays();
  }

  render() { 
    <DayPickerSingleDateController
      {...someProps}
      isOutsideRange={this.isOutsideRange}
      onNextMonthClick={this.handleMonthChange}
    />
  }

}
```

**What i tried**:

- mount/unmount calendar depending on loading prop (problem - animation to next month before nextMount callback + when calendar disappear it looks bad)
- load to store nextMonth data, so when i change view to nextMonth 'isDayBlocked' works good and fetch data for nextMonth (problem - double click on nextMonth change or slow connection)

Any ideas please?

Comment: We'd need more code before figuring out what's wrong. For example when is `isDayBlocked` called?

Comment: It's called on component mount and on month view change. 
Click nextMonth -> `isDayBlocked` called (that's problem because i have old data) -> `GET_DAYS_START` -> `GET_DAYS_SUCCESS` -> now data OK, but i am unable to re-check blocked days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added absolute overlay div with spinner while loading is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Holding your data in state would fix your issue and update your view everytime.

```
  handleMonthChange() {
    // async api fetch
    getNextMonthBlockedDays().then((data) => {
        this.setState({days : data});
    });
  }
```

You can also set a flag to not be able to change the month while a request is processing or you could cancel the previous request. (if your fetch api implements cancellation).

Comment: 1) i keep my data in redux, so my component `DayPicker` is updated, but it is not propagated to `DayPickerSingleDateController` (isDayBlocked not called again)
2) Tried to block click on next while fetching, that component has prop `navNext:element` to support own navigation. But this element is automatically wrapped by button which cause that month change implementation.